# Set makeprg to gradlew

Tags: vim, compiling

First a bit of context for those who don't know gradle. It's basically like `make` except that you don't have to have `gradle` installed on your computer. It ships with projects as a file called `gradlew`. So for instance a gradle project could look like:

```
.
├── gradlew
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── foo
                    └── bar
                        ├── Bar.java
                        ├── Baz.java
                        ├── Foo.java
                        └── Qux.java
```

And from the root directory I can run commands like `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew test` to build/test my code.

Now vim. First I `:set autochdir` in my `.vimrc`. Second, my current buffer is `Foo.java`.

I want to run `:make` which would trigger `../../../../../../gradlew`. How can I set `makeprg` such that no matter what's my `:pwd` it'll call `gradlew` (I guess that could be achieved using `dirname` in a loop but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient/cleanest way to do that).

Thanks.

Comment: Create a script/program that is invoked by vim and recursively searches up the hierarchy for gradlew (be sure to terminate at `/` if not found). The alternative is to put some information in every dir under src, or keep an external database for each directory in a project/the whole disc, both of which would be more efficient on usage, but clumsy to create and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking to do the same thing (or similar things), it's doable by creating a new compiler that use `findfile`, and reuse `errorformat` from some other compiler + slight modifications. The end result looks like:

```
let s:gradlew = escape(findfile('gradlew', '.;') . " -b " . findfile('build.gradle', '.;'), ' \')

if exists("current_compiler")
    finish
endif

if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2      " older Vim always used :setlocal
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

let current_compiler = s:gradlew
execute "CompilerSet makeprg=" . s:gradlew
" copied from javac.vim + added the :compileJava bits
CompilerSet errorformat=%E:compileJava%f:%l:\ %m,%E%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#,%-G%.%#
```

Comment: Awesome. This is so useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To add to foo's comment above, note that it is helpful to add './' to the s:gradlew variable, i.e.:

```
let s:gradlew = escape('./' . findfile('gradlew', '.;') . " -b " . findfile('build.gradle', '.;'), ' \')
```

This will allow gradlew to execute even when the file is in the current working directory. Without this, you may see the error "command not found: gradlew".